# OWL ontology design with protege

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

Hi I am designing an Ontology in which I need to define a data property 'SSN' for a class named 'Person'. Now one restriction, which I am thinking, would be of uniqueness. That is no two instances of class 'Person' should have same SSN. 
My question: How to define such restriction in Protege?

http://www.co-ode.org/resources/reference/manchester_syntax/

defines some restrictions but I think nothing fits in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to define the SSN property as [inverse-functional](http://www.w3.org/wiki/InverseFunctionalProperty). An inverse functional property means that wherever you see a given range value, you know that the subject resource must be the same. So, if `p` is inverse functional, and you have:

```
R0 p N .
R1 p N .
```

then you can infer that `R0` and `R1` must denote the same individual. If you know, through some other axioms, that `R0` and `R1` are in fact different, then a reasoner will report that your model is inconsistent. That's as close as you can get to the consistency checking you want in an [open-world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_world_assumption) knowledge base.

Comment: You can easily assert `R0` and `R1` as different using a Different Individual (`DifferentFrom`) axiom if needed.

Comment: SSN is a data property in my case and not a object property. And inverse-functional is only valid for object properties.

Comment: You could create an individual for each SSN using a URI scheme such as `urn:x-ssn:12345678`, with the actual SSN as a property using `skos:notation`. This would have other potential benefits: for example, you could attach properties showing that a given SSN is valid from and to the dates of birth and (if known) death of the person. There may even be an official URI scheme for SSN's already.